# How to stop apache permanently on mac Mavericks?

Tags: macos, apache, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install zend server on mac and need to uninstall the apache server that is auto included with Mavericks so that the Apache server included with Zend is used instead. Can it be prevented from running on startup or permanently removed?

Comment: Stupid decision to close this, as it is clearly related to software development. In fact, this question would not be acceptable in Server Fault as it does not deal with server administration. Nobody is using Mavericks as a server OS, they are using it on their dev machines, making this a question about dev tools.

Comment: Reeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

This will stop a running instance of Apache, and record that it should not be restarted.  It records your preference in `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist`.

Comment: I get this error  "Error unloading: org.apache.httpd" on osx 10.9

Comment: Edgar, you need to have an apache instance running already for this command to work.  

sudo apachectl start

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Mac 10.10 Yosemite. Says /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service.

Comment: It's not working on Yosemite Beta 5. I get the same message as @cchiera

Comment: Works on Yosemite 5 - apache needs to be running before issuing the command

Comment: @cchiera that's right, apache has to be loading before running that.

Comment: FWIW I started using lunchy which is a nice interface over launchctl: https://github.com/eddiezane/lunchy . `sudo lunchy uninstall apache`

Comment: works in el capitan ,2 days straight figuring out to disable Macs apache and use XAMPP apache , finally !!!

Comment: If it doesn't work, use `sudo killall httpd` and `sudo killall mysqld`

Answer (score 14):

try this

```
sudo killall httpd
```

it will stop all

Comment: This only stops the httpd service. It doesn't prevent it from starting upon restart.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem, and the culprit was pretty obtuse. It wound up that OSX was attempting to include a nonexistent php version, however the OSX httpd was also not directly accessible due to the homebrew httpd taking priority. Here's what I did that fixed it:

First: `brew unlink httpd`
Then `which httpd` revealed the following: `/usr/sbin/httpd`

At this point I ran `sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -k stop`, and the real culprit revealed itself:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 527 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found: _environ\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so\n  Expected in: /usr/sbin/httpd\n in /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so
```

I then fixed this with `sudo vi /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, and commented out all of the lines in that file, and ran the following for good measure:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

This stated:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service
```

The underlying problem was that the native OSX instance was still running, but had become detached from `launchctl` due to the PHP not found issue. So basically `launchctl` thought it had properly shut the process down, but the `apachectl` agent refused to stop due to the PHP error, resulting in a decoupled process, which was only accessible for direct control when the homebrew version was also unlinked.

Commenting out the native PHP include allowed me to run `sudo apachectl -k stop` without issue.

After sorting this out, I then ran

```
brew link httpd
```

followed by

```
brew services restart httpd
```

Profit.

Answer (score 0):

If you got to this page as I did and was getting something like `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service.` try NOT using the sudo command, which was making me get the above error.

Comment: Hmm, even without sudo I get this problem... Any other ideas?

Comment: Tells me `This operation requires root.` without sudo, `apachectl stop`