# Stop High Sierra's httpd/apache and use Homebrews?

Tags: apache, macos-high-sierra

I want to use Homebrew's version of Apache on my Mac so I can start/stop it as I please, so I've been trying all afternoon to stop and unload several httpd processes that are run by user _www on macOS 10.13.3 High Sierra without any luck.

See the screenshot attached, there are 6 httpd processes run by _www and the single process run under root (Homebrew service)

[image: terminal screenshot of running processes]

I've tried

`sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

which gives me an error:

`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service`

I've also tried tracking the process starting them down, switching user to _www (a no no) so I can see where it's being started and so far I'm having no luck.

I want to kill them all, and have them stay dead as right now they're conflicting with the server I'm actually trying to run. Anyone cleverer than me out there that knows how to kill this literal http demon?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20439859/996338

> Try this:
>
> sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
>
> This will stop a running instance of Apache, and record that it should not be restarted. It records your preference in /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist.

For a single session (meaning, between reboots), you can use `sudo apachectl stop`.